# Grab variable name from url

Tags: python, http, variables, flask

I need to grab the variable from URL and use it in my function.  Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

```
from flask import Flask,jsonify
import json
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/films/<name>')
def show_film(name):
    films={'Titanic':1997, 'Transformers':2014, 'X-Men':2014, 
            'The Wolf of Wall Street':2013, 'Iron Man 3':2013}
    for film in films:
        if film==name:
            NameYear = name + ' was released in '+films[film]
    return NameYear


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

Comment: what seems to be the problem?

Comment: Every time i browse that link i get this error "Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application."

Comment: And what is the python error that shown up in your console? ;)

Comment: No errors are in the console.
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/
24.2.209.67 - - [05/Oct/2014 19:49:15] "GET /films/Titanic HTTP/1.1" 500 -
24.2.209.67 - - [05/Oct/2014 19:49:15] "GET /films/Titanic HTTP/1.1" 500 -
24.2.209.67 - - [05/Oct/2014 19:49:52] "GET /films/Wolf%20of%20wall%20street HTTP/1.1" 500 -
24.2.209.67 - - [05/Oct/2014 19:50:06] "GET /films HTTP/1.1" 200 -

Comment: There sure is one, otherwise there would be no internal server error! You can also enable debug mode in flask to display them in browser instead of a error 500.

Comment: Well it works until I go to the page /films/moviename

Comment: Right, but what is the error? In the quickstart it's explained how to turn on debug mode, so the error will be prominent http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/

Comment: Change your ’app.run(host='0.0.0.0')’ to ’app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)’ to see errors. You have a typo in your code: flims

Comment: Thank you you guys so after I turned on debugging, it was showing that the year needs is in int and should be either string or unicode.  After converting it it worked just fine.

Comment: Then please post it as an answer and accept it for future people who will wonder into this page :)

Answer (score 1):

films[films] needs to be converted to string or unicode using str(films[film])